# how to store single values in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am fairly new to salesforce so forgive me if this question has asked before - I have thusfar not been able to figure out what seems like a simple thing to do.

I am working on an app and I would like to have access to a set of initialisation variables (i.e. username, password, URL etc).

Sofar I had a go at using custom labels to hold the information. But the problem here is that I cannot seem to change the value of this label from a visualforce page (I can only display the value).

Then I had a go at using a custom object, giving it the fields I needed. But this confuses me. I don't need to store several sets of variables, I only need one set of variables. Do I really need to store this in a custom object which basically acts as a database table when I am only ever using 1 row? And if this is the case, how do I populate this 1 row without any human interaction (i.e. clicking through the force platform to add entries to this custom object) so that when I install the app somewhere, this one entry is there (containing some default values for each of the columns)?

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Custom Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm) in the "Help & Training". They come in 2 flavors:

- key->value pair with unique keys
- hierarchy (where you can have some default values for organisation as a whole but if you need to override them for certain Users - you can do it too).

Alternatively - if it's very tightly bound to Users (a password to some external system?) why not make custom fields on User object?

Comment: Because I don't want to ask customers who install our app to do a hundred "name"->"setup"->"...." instructions (and that is the only way to add custom fields to a user object isn't it?). The app will contain a tab that displays this set of values & allows for them to be changed. I just need to figure out the best way of storing these values somewhere.

Comment: No, my User record happily shows there's at least 1 custom field that came with a managed package so it's definitely possible. It'd be up to them to fill them in though ;) DataLoader / other API products can be used to mass update Users as well as Custom Settings so that shouldn't be a factor. I'd say - investigate the User route. Also because that way data will be automatically copied to sandboxes upon refresh whereas cust. settings will come blank like other "normal" objects.